# Seaborn displays different color for different run

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, apache-zeppelin

I followed the setting from [here](http://blog.ditullio.fr/2015/11/16/setting-up-zeppelin-for-spark-in-scala-and-python/#Plotting_with_matplotlib) to make matplotlib/seaborn available to display in Zeppelin. However, with the following code:

```
%python

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()

import StringIO

def show(p):
    img = StringIO.StringIO()
    p.savefig(img, format='svg')
    img.seek(0)
    print "%html <div style='width:600px'>" + img.buf + "</div>"

""" Prepare your plot here ... """

# Use the custom show function instead of plt.show()
x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x)
show(sns.plt)
```

It is strange that the displayed figure show the desired lightblue color the first time I run the code but will display different colors if I execute the same piece of code. Is there a way to force seaborn to keep constant color being displayed? Thanks.

Comment: The example you reference seems very confused. Why is it passing `matplotlib.pyplot` (a module) as an argument to the `show()` function? I'd suggest going at this a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what is meant by "running a second time".

However you may try to actually close the figure before running it again. E.g.

```
plt.close("all")
```

in order to make sure, a new figure is created which should have the same default color every time.